# Android send broadcast via interface

Tags: java

I want to share some data between class with interface 
I developed some codes like this :

```
public interface Transmission
{
    public void onBroadcastReceived(String key, String value);
}

public class Events implements Transmission
{
    protected static Events instance;

    public static Events getInstance()
    {
        if(instance == null)
        {
            instance = new Events();
        }
        return instance;
    }
    public void addBroadcast(String key, string value)
    {
        onBroadcastReceived(key, value);
    }
    @override
    public void onBroadcastReceived(String key, String value)
    {

    }
}

public class A
{
    public A()
    {
        Events.getInstance().addBroadcast("Hello", "say hello");
    }
}

public class B implements Transmission
{
    @override
    public void onBroadcastReceived(String key, String value)
    {
        Log.d(key,value);
    }
}

B b = new B();
A a = new A();
```

I am trying to transfer some data with interface , is this possible ?
Is this solution true ?
Will be log key and value in B class  ?
Please advise

Comment: Ya we can use, in android we write the code in java language. so we can write classes,interface i.e present in java language

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: onBroadcastReceived in class B does not work

Comment: Your code wont work if you want Class B to log you need to have its instance on A and pass it to the event class.

Comment: If you want an Custom Broadcast you coud try the following. (http://hmkcode.com/android-sending-receiving-custom-broadcasts/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the following changes to get it work.

```
 public interface Transmission
{
    public void onBroadcastReceived(String key, String value);
}

public class Events     {
    protected static Events instance;

    public static Events getInstance()
    {
        if(instance == null)
        {
            instance = new Events();
        }
        return instance;
    }
    public void addBroadcast(String key, string value,Transmission recever)
    {
        recever.onBroadcastReceived(key, value);
    }

}

public class A
{
    public A()
    {
        B b = new B();
        Events.getInstance().addBroadcast("Hello", "say hello",b);
    }
}

public class B implements Transmission
{
    @override
    public void onBroadcastReceived(String key, String value)
    {
        Log.d(key,value);
    }
}


A a = new A();
```